# Jain-Sip dialog message body

Tags: dialog, jain-sip

I have an app using JAIN-SIP. The application will send SIP NOTIFY messages with event type `dialog` and content-type `application/dialog-info+xml`.

Is there an API for building the (xml) message body. The `javax.sip.message.MessageFactory` takes a `java.lang.Object` for the message body, since the type can vary depending on the request. But are there any libraries to facilitate constructing the format of the body?